# No GUI in Ubuntu after upgrade was interrupted

Tags: gui

I was updating Ubuntu to latest 16.04 version. In between, my laptop got shut down due to overheating. Now on login I am not getting any GUI. It shows a `tty1` login and everything has to be done through command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The command you want to run is:

```
startx
```

This will start the x-server and bring up the GUI.